# C - Counting the frequency of a number in an array

Tags: c

I am trying to calculate the frequency of a value in an array. I thought I was on the right track with my current entry, but it seems to be miscounting the "count." I would love a second opinion on how to correctly show the frequency of the array! Here's what I have:

```
#include <stdio.h>

/************************************************************************/
/*                      Function: frequency                            */
/*                                                                     */
/*  Purpose:    Obtains the frequency of a number in an array          */
/*                                                                     */
/*                                                                     */ 
/*                                                                     */
/*  Parameters: theArray-The array in question                         */
/*              n- the size of the array                               */
/*              x- the number to search for frequency within the array */
/*                                                                     */
/*  Returns:    The frequency of a given number in an array              */
/*                                                                     */
/************************************************************************/

int frequency (int theArray [ ], int n, int x)
{
    int count = 0;
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        if ( theArray[i]=x)
        {
            count = count + 1 ;
        }      
        else
        {
            count = count ;
        } 
    }

      printf ("\nThe frequency of %i in your array is %i ",x,count);
  }

  int main ()
  {
      int i;    
      int theArray[] = {};
      int n;
      int x;


      printf ("Enter The Amount Of Numbers In Your Array: ");
      scanf("%i", &n);/*Stores Amound Of Numbers In The Array*/

      for (i = 0; i < n; ++i)
      {
          printf("\nEnter number for array: ");     
          scanf ("%i", &theArray[i]);
      }

      printf ("\nOK, Thanks! Now What Number Do You Want To Search For Frequency In Your Array? ");
      scanf("%i", &x);/*Stores Number To Search For Frequency*/

      frequency(theArray,n,x);

      return(0);  /* success */

  } /* main */
```

Comment: Just as a quick comment.. If you have an if statement which does something, and an else which does nothing, just omit the else! Also, you've declared your frequency function to return an int value. Currently it returns nothing. You should change int to void, or return a value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

3 things

1. in `if ( theArray[i]=x)`   `=` should be `==`
2. the whole else `{count = count;}` is redundant.
3. the function should be `void`

Comment: About number 1, That `if` will always be true in that form.

Answer (score 3):

`if ( theArray[i]=x)` should be `==`.

And the whole `else {count = count;}` is redundant.

And you don't actually return the count (or anything else) - even though the signature says you do.

Answer (score 3):

You have a typo:

```
if ( theArray[i] = x )
```

should be:

```
if ( theArray[i] == x )
```

The former would set `theArray[i]` to `x` and will always return true for the if statement, whereas what you want to do is the second one which is a logical equivalency check.

On a side note, your `else` statement is also redundant, you dont need the `else { count=count; }` part. Additionally, your function is not returning a value, so it is better to change the return value from `int` to `void`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't add elements to an array after it has been created.
int theArray[] = {};
...is an empty array.

You'll have to:

1. Ask for the size of the array
2. Dynamically create the array (using malloc())
3. Add the numbers
4. Pass the array into frequency() as a pointer
5. Delete the array before exiting (using free())

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#define MAX 10
int flag=0;
void display(int no,int cnt,int visi[]);

void main()
{
  int arr[]={1,1,1,2,3,4,2,2,3,1};
  int visited[MAX];
  int i,j,no,cnt=1;
  clrscr();
  for(i=0;i<10;i++)
  {
    no=arr[i];
    cnt=1;
    for(j=i+1;j<10;j++)
    {
      if(no==arr[j])
        cnt++;
    }
    display(no,cnt,visited);
  }
}

void display(int no,int cnt,int visited[])
{
  int static i;
  int j;

  if(flag==1)
    for(j=0;j<=i;j++)
    {
      if(visited[j]==no)
        return;
    }
  i++;
  flag=1;
  printf("\n%d=%d",no,cnt);
  visited[i]=no;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){
    int n, t, i, j, arr[30],len, halflen,flag=0,count=0;

    printf("Enter number of elements to insert in an array:");
    scanf("%d",&len);
    printf("Enter elements to insert in an array:");
    for(i=0;i<len;i++){
        scanf("%d",&t);
        arr[i]=t;
    }
    printf("\n");

    /*****************************/
    for(i=0;i<len;i++){
        count=1;
        for(j=i+1;j<=len-1;j++){
            if(arr[i]==arr[j] && arr[i]!='\0'){
                count++;
                arr[j]='\0';
            }
        }
        if(arr[i]!='\0'){
            printf("%d is %d times.\n",arr[i],count);
        }
    }

    /*****************************/
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```